# How to create custom ASP.NET MVC model binder with defalut validation messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Because MVC binds using invariant culture when GET method is used for request, I want to send form culture as query string parameter and use custom MVC binder which on GET method and culture set in url binds using given culture to parse values of model.

I have found some examples of binders and this is what I have hooked now. This binds as expected, but validation does not work and throws exception if model value is wrong.

How can I do it better, including default validation messages, please?

```
public class AppModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != null && value.AttemptedValue != null && value.AttemptedValue != "")
        {
            // customize get request binding (dafult one uses invariant culture)
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Get.Method)
            {
                // try to get query string culture
                var queryCultureName = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["Culture"];
                if (queryCultureName != null)
                {
                    CultureInfo queryCulture;
                    try
                    {
                        queryCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(queryCultureName);

                        return value.ConvertTo(bindingContext.ModelType, queryCulture);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, ex);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext); // System.NullReferenceException is thrown here when invalid value is sent
    }
}
```